# Rails - Bundle install failing due to missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

New to rails here

When I run `bundle install` it keeps failing due to some missing gem

Then I install that missing gem, and I run `bundle install` again, and it fails to another missing gem. And so on, etc.

Is there a way for me to find out what gems are missing so I can just install all of them? My gemfile is just the basic one I generated with `rails new my_app -d mysql` and I've added nothing else.

The gems it's telling me install are not even listed in that gemfile

Thanks for any tips

Comment: What operating system you are using? and are you using RVM or system ruby?

Comment: @RameshKumarThiyagarajan Running on Windows. Not sure what RVM is. I used the RailsInstaller from RubyOnRails main website

Comment: Ricky, developing Ruby on Rails on windows ,is pain full, try ubuntu with vagrant

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.0/node-v4.3.0-x86.msi). Nodejs is used for a gems like "Uglifier".

After install Nodejs, run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

What does the command `ruby -v` give you ?
Is your ruby version 2.0 or above? 

Can you paste your error please.
Try to install nodejs too, sometimes it can be missing.

Comment: Running on Windows. `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]`

Comment: Should I upgrade to v2.0.0? Maybe this is why @SarahCoudert